# Swift multiple UITexView resign responder handling

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am having two `textview` one I placed into view another one within `UIAlertController`. Here, I added `done` and `cancel` button on `keyboard accessory` with actions. Now, how to create resign responder for both `UITextView`?

```
@IBAction func doneClick(_ sender: Any) {
    self.descriptionTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    self.textView.resignFirstResponder() // Its making crash sometime 
}
```

Comment: please post crash message

Comment: @Sh_Khan Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: When another SO user asks you to provide additional information, it is seen as good practice to update your answer. You can do this by clicking the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58080323/edit) button at the end of the text of your question, insert a line or write "Update", then add the information. In this way, another user coming to your question has all the information in the question body and they are not forced to read through comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that one of them is nil at some time , so You can do

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Or make them optional like

```
self.descriptionTextView?.resignFirstResponder()
self.textView?.resignFirstResponder()
```

Comment: if I give this alertviewcontroller Textview not dismissing keyboard.

Comment: you have 2 options try them like above and see ?